# How to store an address of a cell in one sheet and use that address to guide active cell to go to same cell in different sheet?

Tags: excel, vba

I have written this code to consolidate data from different sheets to sheet names as "Graded_File"
The header of data that we receive keep on changing sometime it will be 2 rows header sometime 3 rows so I wanted to make a macaro which can perform no matter how the header is.

I have added the header format in the "Graded_File" sheet and using the below code I am able to select the cell which is below the header and wants to store that cell address and use the same while selecting the range from where I have to copy

Sharing the code for the reference:

```
Public Sub consolidate()

    Dim i As Integer
    
    Dim StartRow As Integer
    Dim StartColumn As Integer
    
    Worksheets("Graded_File").Select
    Range("A1048576").Select
    Selection.End(xlUp).Select
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select 'I want to store this cell address !!
    
    StartRow = ActiveCell.Row
    StartColumn = ActiveCell.Column
            
    For i = 1 To Worksheets.Count - 2
    
    Worksheets(i).Select 
' I want to use the stored address cell location in this range 
    Range("StartRow", "StartColumn").Select 
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
    Selection.Copy
    
    Worksheets("Graded_File").Select
    Range("A1048576").Select
    Selection.End(xlUp).Select
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    
    Next i

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use **.Address** to get the cell address.

Here is some example code.

```
Sub GetAddress()

Dim strAddress As String

    Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    Range("A10").Select
'Select a sheet and a cell
    strAddress = ActiveCell.Address
'Store the address
    MsgBox strAddress
'Show the address

    Sheets("Sheet2").Select
'Select another sheet
    Range(strAddress).Select
'Select the address
    

End Sub
```

If you would rather use the **.Row** and **.Column** to work with the cell.

Here is some example code.

```
Sub GetRowColumn()

Dim lngRow As Long
Dim lngColumn As Long
Dim wsSource As Worksheet
Dim rngSource As Range
Dim wsTarget As Worksheet
Dim rngTarget As Range


    Set wsSource = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set rngSource = wsSource.Range("A10")
'Set the source worksheet and range
    
    lngRow = rngSource.Row
    lngColumn = rngSource.Column
'Get the cell row and column

        MsgBox "Row: " & lngRow & vbCrLf & "Column: " & lngColumn
'Show the address
    
    Set wsTarget = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")
    Set rngSource = wsTarget.Cells(lngRow, lngColumn)
'Set the target worksheet and range
    
    wsTarget.Activate
    rngSource.Select
'Select the target worksheet and cell

End Sub
```

Comment: for range function it will work I want to use rows function 
rows(rowindex, columnindex)
for the above example as you mentioned string is there any way to store the string rin rows index 

so how I can use that

Comment: Expanded the answer.